# Retrieve image from an aspx URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I am trying to get my Visual C# program to download an image from a URL that ends in .aspx. This image is actually a captcha code, and it changes with time.

What I have tried to do thus far is create a PictureBox, and I have set the ImageLocation to the ASPX url that returns an image.

However, this gives me nothing but a red boxed X where the captcha image should have appeared.

Is there some code I should type? Sorry for my lack of understanding, I'm a newbie at this C# business!

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can try downloading the image manually to see if you get a valid image

```
using (WebClient webclient = new WebClient())
{
    using (var imageStream = webclient.OpenRead("http://example.com/image.png"))
    {
        Image img = Image.FromStream(imageStream);                   
    }
}
```

If you don't get a valid image, you can then try `var str = webclient.DownloadString("http://example.com/image.png");` and inspect the `str` variable to see if you get some error text data from the webserver instead of an image.

Comment: Why not just set the ImageLocation to the url of the image instead of the aspx page?

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the prompt reply. When I insert the URL for the Captcha, Visual Studio throws an exception, saying WebException was unhandled - The underlying connection was closed.

Comment: @slugster, somehow thought about winforms, setting the URL should work fine, but for diagnostics purposes you can try the above code to see if you can download the image at all.

Comment: Hello! Thanks! I will inspect the str later on. It seems that I have managed to load the image by spoofing the user-agent of the application. By inserting the useragent of an iPhone, the image loaded perfectly.

Comment: @user806868 then your URL is invalid or the image server has some idea that you are not allowed to link to that image. Can you see the image if you just type in the url in a browser?

Comment: Yes, I can load the image without problems in Chrome or IE. It seems like the server is configured to reject connections to clients without a user-agent. After I added the useragent to webclient.headers, the image loaded perfectly. What useragent didn't matter, as long as there was one.

Comment: @Albin, using the str method returned weird characters. But it's alright now as I have solved the problem, which was a missing user-agent string!

Comment: @user, add that as a proper answer below, then mark it as the answer after the minimum time delay has passed (there is a period of time before you can self-mark your own answer). Then the answer doesn't get lost in the middle of a bunch of comments.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everybody who has helped out in answering this question!

I was dealing with a rather picky server which would only allow clients with a valid user-agent to access the site it was hosting. Adding:

```
webclient.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; SV1; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.0.30618)2011-09-18 00:09:44";
```

solved the problem.

Thanks!